# How to drag and drop list item from ASP:Listbox control into ASP:Textbox?

Tags: asp.net, forms, textbox, drag-and-drop, listbox

I am using asp:Listbox to retrieve data from from table and want to be able to drag a list item from the asp:Listbox control and drop it into the asp:Textbox control.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Cleared format, removed thanks and gave more specific tags